# Determine error in Neville's Algorithm calculation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I've been mulling over this problem for a while and I don't even know how to start it. The book is hopelessly vague.

The problem states

> Neville's Algorithm is used to approximate $f(0)$ using $f(-2), f(-1), f(1), f(2)$. Suppose $f(-1)$ was understated by 2 and $f(1)$ was overstated by 3. Determine the error in the original calculation of the value of the interpolating polynomial to approximate $f(0)$.

According to the book, the proper answer is:

> The incorrect approximation is $\frac{-f(2)}{6}+\frac{2f(1)}{3}+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2f(-1)}{3} - \frac{f(-2)}{6}$ and the correct approximation is $\frac{-f(2)}{6}+\frac{2f(1)}{3}+\frac{2f(-1)}{3}-\frac{f(-2)}{6}$ so the incorrect approximation is $\frac{4}{3}$ too large.

But I have no idea how they even got this. Can someone please walk me through this problem? My homework assigns a similar problem, and this is the problem from the book that does a similar thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: @lhf Numerical Analysis, 9th Ed.

Comment: Burden and Faires?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should determine the interpolating polynomial $P(x)$ passing by the 4 points $(x_{-2},y_{-2}) = (-2,f(-2))$, $(x_{-1},y_{-1}) = (-1,f(-1))$, $(x_{1},y_{1}) = (1,f(1))$ and $(x_{2},y_{2}) = (2,f(2))$.

Then, evaluate the polynomial $P$ in $x=0$ and you should get the "correct approximation".

Now restart the whole process with a second interpolating polynomial $Q(x)$ passing by the 4 **modified** points. Again, evaluate the polynomial $Q$ in $x=0$ and you should find the "incorrect approximation".

The error, well, is just the difference between the two.